# Extract records based on difference between two timestamps -postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, timestamp, extract

I have the following columns with hundreds of thousands of entries

```
date_for_trx , date_user_creation , order_number ,  email 
1554377107 .      1554377105              on234524 .    321@gmail.com
1554377000 .      1354377107              on876568 .    xyz@gmail.com
1554377105 .      1254377107              on777612 .    123@gmail.com
1554377107 .      1551177107              on123345 .    abc@gmail.com
......            .......                 .......       ........
```

I need to extract the emails where the difference between date_for_trx (-)and date_user_creation is >=12 months

So it would be emails that have a date_for_trx of 21/03/2019 and a date_user_creation is 21/03/2018 or older

Anyone can help?
Thank you

I tried answers from other questions here but can quite get there.

What I always get is the calculation of time between two timestamps but can extract the emails based on that calculation being 12 months

Comment: Where's that calculation you are talking about? I don't see that in your question.

Comment: I don't see any timestamps in the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL, you can take the difference in years, multiply by 12 and add the difference between month parts that can be negative.

```
SELECT email FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE ((DATE_PART('year', to_timestamp(date_for_trx)::date) - DATE_PART('year', to_timestamp(date_user_creation)::date)) * 12 +
          (DATE_PART('month', to_timestamp(date_for_trx)::date) - DATE_PART('month', to_timestamp(date_user_creation)::date))) >= 12;
```

Comment: I tried it but doesnt get the result i need,  because the difference isnt always that the user_created is 6 or more months older than date_for trx .  
email date_for_trx date_user_created
email1 2018-12-21 9:08 2018-12-19
email2 2018-12-07 17:58 2015-06-25
email3 2018-12-21 9:05 2016-12-17
email4 2018-12-06 17:17 2018-06-18
email5 2018-12-21 9:47 2017-10-27
email6 2018-12-07 17:09 2015-05-07
email7 2018-12-07 16:59 2016-04-10
email8 2018-12-07 17:30 2013-04-09
email9 2018-12-21 9:48 2018-12-20
  
email9 is in the same month/year

Comment: You can use this 
`SELECT email FROM YOUR_TABLE where to_timestamp(date_for_trx) - to_timestamp(date_user_creation) >= interval '365 days'
`
In the **interval**, you can change for you need.
Ex:
interval '6 month', 
interval '1 year',
interval '120 days'

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract the two values and compare the result:

```
where to_timestamp(date_for_trx) - to_timestamp(date_user_creation) >= interval '12 month'
```

Note that the above assumes `date_for_trx` is bigger than `date_user_creation`. It does not handle negative values.